# How to pip install from github....powershell gives error Cannot find command 'git'?

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

I'm trying install psycopg2 into my virtualenv. I've tried pip I've tried easy_install nothing is working... installing from pip is the more desirable choice but it has to be done through nwcell's github package  https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows heres the command I've been using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py34#egg=psycopg2
```

Comment: As a side note, is this _still_ necessary on Windows? I thought [Christoph Gohlke's wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg) took care of all the problems (and you can install them just by downloading the `.whl` and `pip install foo.whl`, or just straight off HTTP)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) say:

> pip supports installing from Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar, and detects the type of VCS using url prefixes: "git+", "hg+", "bzr+", "svn+".
>
> pip requires a working VCS command on your path: git, hg, svn, or bzr.

So, if you don't have a working `git` command on your `%PATH%`, you can't `pip install git+<anything>`. To fix it, [install `git`](http://git-scm.com/downloads), and make sure it ends up on your `%PATH%`.

Comment: If you're running from the command line, you might have to restart it after modifying your PATH for it to recognize it